# copy spreadsheet to a specific folder and remove viewers from the copy

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a copy of the active spreadsheet to a specific folder, then remove all editors from the copied spreadsheet and keep myself as Owner.

Here is my code :

```
//Save Spreadsheet in selected folder 

function freezeSS(vname,option) {

if (vname != ""){


var mainSs =           SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var SSID =             mainSs.getId();
var CopyDate =         Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yy-HH:mm"); // Function Date + Format
var file =             DriveApp.getFileById(SSID);


if (option == "Public") {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B_EpGZ420rEUfk1mZ2Z3RmFKUk9xaGd1bm1CdGhmZ0FCbTdVT2p2MUlJY3NZUTV0MTR0LTQ");
    file.makeCopy(vname + "_" + CopyDate, folder);
}

else {

    var folder =       DriveApp.getFolderById("0B_EpGZ420rEUfk9jTl81NXNVOXNhRDF2N2R4c1FGTW9wQTB5Q3dNS25nd1NEejBTWWd1RFk");
    var backup =       file.makeCopy(vname + "_" + CopyDate, folder);
    var editors =      backup.getEditors().getEmail();
    Logger.log(editors);
    var permision =    backup.removeEditor(editors);

} 
} return false;
}
```

Everything works but I have a problem in removing editors. I always get an error and still have the same editors as in the original spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation states, you have 2 options for removeEditor():

```
removeEditor(user)
```

or

```
removeEditor(emailAddress)
```

You're using neither, you'll need to make a loop in the getEditors() without the getEmail(), this one will also get into the loop, as so:

```
var editors =      backup.getEditors();
for( i in editors ){
  var email = editors[i].getEmail();
  var permision = backup.removeEditor(email);
}
```

or shorter:

```
var editors = backup.getEditors();
    for( i in editors )
      var permision = backup.removeEditor(editors[i]);
```

BTW, this was well documented, a ctrl+c ctrl+v from there would almost solve your problem, please take a little more time to fiddle with it.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user#getEmail();